# Can i define parameters with Classes in Restler?

Tags: laravel, restler

I want to declare params with differenc classes when i have a GET endpoint.

Example:

```php
/**
* @param ClassA a
* @param ClassB b
...
public function getSomething() {}

public ClassA {
    /**
    * @param int
    */
    public $i;
}

public ClassB {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the class as a parameter works fine. See https://restler5.luracast.com/examples/_016_forms/readme.html Users class makes use of Address class

```
/**
 * @param string  $firstName
 * @param string  $lastName
 * @param string  $email
 * @param string  $password
 * @param Address $address
 *
 * @return array
 *
 * @view users
 */
function postSignUp($firstName, $lastName, $email, $password, $address)
{
    return func_get_args();
}
```

Address class is as follows

```
<?PHP
class Address
{
    public $blockNumber;
    public $streetName;
    public $floor;
    public $unitNumber;
    public $country;
    public $postalCode;
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. But i have a get function and the Class parameter doesn't work. I mean i would like the variables to be query params.